# React Native - Axios Login Request with Form Fails with 500

Tags: javascript, react-native, rest, authentication, axios

First of all, there are a lot of questions like this however I couldn't make it work using them.

I can request to server for login over Postman successfully.

**Body**

[image]

**Headers**

[image]

However, If I request using Axios within my app response is 500.

**Building Form**

```
const formData  = new FormData()

formData.append('email', 'eray@serviceUser.com')
formData.append('password', '12121212')

dispatch(FetchLogin.action(formData))
```

**Axios Instance**

```
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: Config.API_URL,
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Authorization",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
  },
  timeout: 3000,
})
```

I believe Axios adds the `Content-Length` and `Host` to header automatically.

**Request**

```
export default async credentials => {
  if (!credentials) {
    return handleError({ message: 'Credentials are required' })
  }
  const response = await api.post('user/login/', credentials)
  console.log('LOGIN response:: ', JSON.stringify(response, null, 2))
  return response.data
}
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 0):

If you are using http url

for android make sure **AndroidManifest.xml** have

```
<application
  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" tools:targetApi="28"> 
... 
</application>
```

for ios make sure **Project/Info.plist** have

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
  ...
</dict>
```